# Restart animation on every new trigger event

Tags: angular, animation, css-animations

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fki9bm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

When I hit the button slowly every 2seconds its exactly what im looking for.
Every trigger event should start at opacity: 0 => opacity: 1.

=> so if I spam the animate button the div should be "invisible" as its always near opacity: 0

I need a general solution because my usecase has n-different trigger states.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want, but if you want `opacity` to switch with `status` every time, you can use the `state` operator to define the style of the corresponding `status`.

```js
animations: [
  trigger("slideStatus", [
    state("active", style({ opacity: 1, offset: 1 })),
    state("inactive", style({ opacity: 0, offset: 0 })),
    transition("* => active", [animate("2s")]),
    transition("* => inactive", [animate("2s")])
  ])
]
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fki9bm-4nuth5

Comment: I know this solution but "I need a general solution because my usecase has n-different trigger states." (from OP). How can I generalize this without any specific stateNames ?

Comment: hey thank you. I looked at your stacklblitz. It should always go from opacity 0 to 1 on each state. Not toggle back and forth. Whenever the value change it should fade out and come back.

Comment: therefore when I hit the button repeatetely the div should be "invisible"

Answer (score 0):

Updated my https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fki9bm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

it was suprisingly easy

```
<nav>
  <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle Status</button>
</nav>

<div [@dimming]="status" class="box">
  {{ status == 'active' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}
</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['status-slider.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('dimming', [

      transition('* => *', [
        animate('1s', keyframes([
          style({ opacity: 0, offset: 0.5}),
          style({ opacity: 1, offset: 1}),
        ])),
      ]),

    ])
  ]
```